# Sub string a variable with variable

Tags: batch-file

I have a .bat file that needed to substring a variable with another variable.
The the substring will be inside a loop. I have two variable inside this loop.

```
echo %%i  

echo %targetPath%
```

%%i is the full string. And I have to remove part of %%i if found a match string with %targetPath%

My coding which is not working.

```
echo  %%i%:%targetPath%=%
```

My couldn't get it to work because I am confused with the %%name and %name%. This is my expected result. In php , we have a substring function that able to pass the fullstring into substring function and a keyword to be match. And this is what I trying to achieve

```
fullstr=abcdefghijk
keyword=abcd

result=efghijk
```

Current working code

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

set "targetPath=%~dp0in"

for /r "%targetPath%" %%i in (.) do (

set "str=%%i"
echo  !str:%targetPath%=!

)
```

Current output

```
echo  !str:C:\Users\vuser01\Desktop\Texture Packer\libgdxtools\in=!
```

Comment: This type of management is fully described at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990), although the topic is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html):

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "target=some"
for %%i in ("something") do (
 set "var=%%i"
 echo !var:%target%!
)
```

Comment: can it done without a loop? I am trying to make it simple as possible as I am not familiar with writing batch. I have updated my question to provide more information

Comment: @LeonArmstrong - you can.Just you mentioned that your code is withing a for loop.

Comment: echo  !str:%targetPath%=! I try to use this line within the code , it is not running

Comment: @LeonArmstrong do you have the `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion` line before that?

Comment: Yes I have , I edited the question to provide more information , guess I have other syntax that affect the output.